# iPhone 5s. If you are connected to wifi at home and the wifi temporarily loses signal does the iPhone automatically switch back to cellular network?

Tags: wifi, iphone

I want to know if you are connected to your home wifi, and that wifi temporarily loses signal for a few hours, does the iPhone automatically start using your cellular network?

I had an issue with my Find Friends App not showing my location for a while, even though I never shut it off.  I am just wondering if this could be the cause.

Comment: When you say "looses signal" does that mean the phone is still connected to the router but the router is no longer connected to your ISP?

Answer (score 1):

This has changed since iOS 9 with [Wi-Fi Assist](https://support.apple.com/HT205296)

> With Wi-Fi Assist, you can stay connected to the Internet even if you have a poor Wi-Fi connection. For example, if you're using Safari with a poor Wi-Fi connection and a webpage doesn't load, Wi-Fi Assist will activate and automatically switch to cellular so that the webpage continues to load. You can use Wi-Fi Assist with most apps like Safari, Apple Music, Mail, Maps, and more.

---

Prior to iOS 9…
No, unfortunately not.

If the WiFi signal itself is still 'live' the iPhone doesn't check to see if it's actually connected to the outside world, unfortunately. It will just spin its wheels waiting for data that never arrives.

You need to switch it over manually.